# Set default GDAL/OGR config options?

Tags: gdal, command-line

Is there a method to save GDAL/OGR Utilities `--config` default options?

For example I almost always want to use the [gdaladdo](/questions/tagged/gdaladdo) option for smallest possible jpeg-in-tiff overviews, but that's a lot of frequent typing and/or pasting:

```
--config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL
```

Can I set my shell to always use those options unless I specifically want otherwise? (Windows CMD most of the time, but Linux answer would be good too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly - no, I don't think it's possible.

To workaround, use the *nix [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) concept...

On Windows:

- You can make your current method permanent by using `setx` or the Windows user environment variables GUI.
- You can fake an alias by setting an env var to the command + config options (note need to open a new cmd prompt to use the env var set by setx, note lack of "=" and entire command must be on one line):

```
setx gdaljpgo "gdaladdo -r gauss --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW=YCBCR --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW=JPEG --config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW=85"
```

```
C:\> %gdaljpgo% input.tif 2 4 8 16 32
```

- You can use a shell that directly supports aliases, such as [Windows Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)#Windows_PowerShell) or (my fave) the Git for Windows Bash prompt.
- You can use the `doskey` command to set an alias/macro (note limitations in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/560558))

On Linux:

- set an alias in your shell startup, i.e. `~/.bashrc`.

```
alias gdaljpgo='gdaladdo -r gauss \
                         --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW=YCBCR \
                         --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL \
                         --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW=JPEG \
                         --config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW=85'
```

Comment: Accepted as best practical and immediately available solution. Ideal would be for GDAL to load dot-gdal files following standard 'nix practice, a feature request waiting to happen. ;-)

Comment: More on Windows aliases and doskey: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: @Matt, one advantage of Win doskey over Win env vars or *nix aliases (though you can also do this with a bash function instead of an alias) is easily access arguments, so you could include overview levels in the"alias", `doskey gdaljpgo=gdaladdo -r gauss etc... $1 2 4 8 16 32` where $1 will substitute the filename argument. Looks more painful to setup permanent doskey commands though.

Comment: Oh, arguments access is a good point! (Won't be needed for gdaladdo in 2.3+ though, which calcs number of levels automatically)

Answer (score 2):

Your "set _opts" method is a tricky way for doing the same that is directly supported by `--optfile` http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html

> --optfile file
>
> Read the named file and substitute the contents into the command line options list. Lines beginning with # will be ignored. Multi-word
>   arguments may be kept together with double quotes.

It is also possible to set the system level environmental variables with "export" or "set" https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions which will make them defaults for GDAL. The problem is that then the user may not know or remember what the defaults are. Optfile saves most part of writing, user still has full control for what happens, and it is easy to make different optfiles for example for jpeg compressed overviews for aerial images and deflate compressed ones for raster maps.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `--optfile`. I discarded and consequently forgot about this approach because typing `gdaladdo --optfile %HOME%\gdal.opt` is still too much. I guess what I'm looking at is a feature request for gdal utils to pick up the file automatically if it exists.

Comment: There should be many optfiles because what would be fine default optfile for gdaladdo would make no sense at all for ogr2ogr or gdal_translate.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do now:

```
set _opts= -r gauss ^
--config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW=YCBCR ^
--config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL ^
--config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW=JPEG ^
--config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW=85

gdaladdo %_opts% infile.tif
```

It's not ideal, but works to some extent. I'm happy to drop it for a more comprehensive solution (such as reading .gdal file in HOME?)